# How to create a nested dictionary from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(id:{1,2,1,4,4},
course:{math,math,sci,art,math},
result:{pass,pass,fail,fail,fail}}
```

I want to create a nested dictionary like this:
for every ID, I want to make a nested dictionary of passed courses and failed courses.

```
{id:{pass:{courses},fail:{courses}}}

{1:{pass:{math},fail:{sci}},2:{pass:{math}},4:{fail:{art,math}}}
```

Comment: both the input and output are nor valid python, can you please ensure that the objects can be defined in a python shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,1,4,4],
'course':['math','math','sci','art','math'],
'result':['pass','pass','fail','fail','fail']})


df.groupby(['result', 'id'])['course'].agg(list).unstack().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1: {'fail': ['sci'], 'pass': ['math']},
 2: {'fail': nan, 'pass': ['math']},
 4: {'fail': ['art', 'math'], 'pass': nan}}
```

Well, yes, peaking at @mozway solution, use `set` instead of `list`:

```
df.groupby(['result', 'id'])['course'].agg(set).unstack().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1: {'fail': {'sci'}, 'pass': {'math'}},
 2: {'fail': nan, 'pass': {'math'}},
 4: {'fail': {'art', 'math'}, 'pass': nan}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this input:

```
   id course result
0   1   math   pass
1   2   math   pass
2   1    sci   fail
3   4    art   fail
4   4   math   fail
```

You can use nested groupby:

```
out = (df.groupby('id')
         .apply(lambda g: g.groupby('result')['course']
                           .agg(set).to_dict())
         .to_dict()
       )
```

output:

```
{1: {'fail': {'sci'}, 'pass': {'math'}},
 2: {'pass': {'math'}},
 4: {'fail': {'art', 'math'}}}
```

Or a pivot table:

```
(df.pivot_table(columns='id', index='result', values='course', aggfunc=set)
   .to_dict()
)
```

output:

```
{1: {'fail': {'sci'}, 'pass': {'math'}},
 2: {'fail': nan, 'pass': {'math'}},
 4: {'fail': {'art', 'math'}, 'pass': nan}}
```